# Prefect UI cannot connect to Orion API when deployed on a remote virtual machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prefect

## Setup

I have a Physical Machine (PM) running on Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) and a remote Virtual Machine (VM) running on AlmaLinux 8.7 (Stone Smilodon) on the same network.

## Goal

I would like to run a container with a Prefect server on the VM and to access the Prefect UI from anywhere on the network by requesting `http://<VM_ip>:4200`.
This would allow for a local development of the new Flows and then a simple way to run them. (For anyone who may have used the `docker-compose.yaml` from Airflow, I would like to reproduce this behavior)

## Issue

On my PM, I can run Prefect either directly (`prefect orion start`), or in a container (`docker run --network host -it prefecthq/prefect:2-latest prefect orion start`). In these cases, I can see the relevant Flows' executions, etc.
The problem arises when I try to relocate my Prefect server onto my VM.
It seems whatever I tries, I ultimately end up with a `Can't connect to Orion API at http://0.0.0.0:4200/api. Check that it's accessible from your machine.` error message when trying to open the Prefect UI on my PM. Other than this, Prefect seems to be running correctly in the container (*i.e* I can `build`, `apply` and `run` Flow deployments)

## What have I tried

The main thing I have tried is the following command:

```bash
docker run \
  --name prefect \
  --env PREFECT_ORION_API_HOST=0.0.0.0 \
  -v ~/containers/prefect/deployments:/deployments \
  -p 4200:4200 \
  -d prefecthq/prefect:2-latest \
  prefect orion start
```

As far as I understood it, it should have done the same as the container deployment on the PM, while exposing the port `4200` to authorize access from outside.

## Where I have looked

I tried asking my question on the [Prefect Discourse](https://discourse.prefect.io/t/deploy-prefect-in-a-container-on-a-remote-vm/1915) but, while I have received answers, none of them seem to have done the trick. Among the answers was looking into the [Prefect Docker compose method](https://github.com/rpeden/prefect-docker-compose), but this also fails in the same fashion.

Where is the error here? Is it at all possible? Thanks for reading, commenting and answering!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a following setup:, dev laptop, on which I would like to see UI, and a server bare metal, where I run my flows. Apparently you need one prefect server to run flows, agents, deployment etc and the second prefect server on dev machine to serve as an UI. How I set it up so it works:

On the server machine I have a prefect server service run by:

`prefect server start --host 0.0.0.0`

Prefect profile on server has set:

`PREFECT_API_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:4200/api"`

On my dev machine, where I would like to see UI I run the second server service, where I point to API of the one on the server machine:

`PREFECT_API_URL = "http://ip.of.my.server:4200/api"`

Weirdly enough it does not work if I try to access it on my dev machine from 127.0.0.1:4200 but it works if I access localhost:4200

Comment: This helped me! I kept setting the `PREFECT_API_URL` to my virtual machine's IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```bash
docker run -p 4200:4200 prefecthq/prefect:2-latest prefect orion start --host 0.0.0.0
prefect config set PREFECT_API_URL = "http://0.0.0.0:4200/api"
```

Comment: Thanks again for your answer.
Firstly, if I understand correctly, these commands can't be executed this way. The former would start the Orion server while the latter wouldn't have been executed yet. Also, the latter would only be executed once the former has been exited.
After testing it anyway, it indeed returns the error mentioned [in the Discourse](https://discourse.prefect.io/t/deploy-prefect-in-a-container-on-a-remote-vm/1915/18?u=gregoirepelegrin) `Can't connect to Orion API at http://127.0.0.1:4200/api`.

Comment: Alternatively, testing the following `docker run -it -p 4200:4200 prefecthq/prefect bash` then `prefect config set PREFECT_API_URL="http://0.0.0.0:4200/api"` and then `prefect orion start --host 0.0.0.0` (which is what I did [in this Discourse post](https://discourse.prefect.io/t/deploy-prefect-in-a-container-on-a-remote-vm/1915/20?u=gregoirepelegrin)), returns the same error as in the beginning.

Comment: `PREFECT_API_URL = "http://0.0.0.0:4200/api` seems pretty wrong. `0.0.0.0` is the address of a network. It should be `http://127.0.0.1:4200` instead. This is the pointer to the current machine at the published docker-container-port `4200`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that orion is sending requests directly to your local machine in terms of API requests, as opposed to routing them through the backend server to the API server that is also running on your VM as a part of Orion. In my opinion, this is not a sane default, but that's how it's currently implemented.

To solve, you need to supply the public ip address of your virtual machine as `PREFECT_ORION_API_HOST`.